# How to display and legend two types of color in ax.scatter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to display two types of color according to the difference of label. In detail, when label = 2, the points color is black, and rest of points follow the cmap ='Dark2'. I only have one simple idea to overlap the points (label = 2) again, the code like that,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from collections import Counter
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = iris.feature_names)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
points = ax.scatter(df.values[:,0], 
    df.values[:,1],
    c = y,
    cmap='Dark2')  #others is follow this cmap

for i in range (len(y)):
    if y[i] == 2:
        ax.scatter(df.values[i,0],df.values[i,1], c = 'k') #when label = 2,points color is black 

handles, _ = points.legend_elements()
labels =sorted([f'{item}: {count}' for item, count in Counter(y).items()])
ax.legend(handles, labels, loc = "lower right",title = 'clusters')  

plt.show()
```

Now, the problem is color of black points still follow previous color map, like (is grey not black). How to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Now the problem is it shows error "c' argument has 555 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 555, 'y' with size 555. in the line of "cmap= 'Dark2' when I correct in my actual code, I am sure if it is too long in dataset so it cannot recognize label as color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution, but you can manually add one more marker to the legend:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from collections import Counter
iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = iris.feature_names)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

df1 = df[y!= 2] 
points = ax.scatter(df1.values[:,0], df1.values[:,1], marker = 'o', c = y[y!=2], cmap='Dark2') 

df2 = df[y== 2] 
points2 = ax.scatter(df2.values[:,0], df2.values[:,1], marker = 'o', color = 'k')

handles, _ = points.legend_elements()
labels = sorted([f'{item}: {count}' for item, count in Counter(y).items()])

one_more = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='k', marker='o', linestyle='None', markersize = handles[0].get_ms())
ax.legend(handles + [one_more], labels, loc = "lower right",title = 'clusters')  
plt.show()
```

It gives:

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks, but my actual code show some error in line of cmap, it shows: 'c' argument has 555 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 555, 'y' with size 555.  Can I only change the code part of legend? I mean overlap the color in legend?

Comment: @4daJKong If you want to do it with minimal modifications to your code, then you could: 1) add to your code `import matplotlib.lines as mlines`,  2) after you define `handles` add the line from my code that defines `one_more`,  3) in your code replace the line `ax.legend(handles, ...)` with `ax.legend(handles[:-1] + [one_more], ...)` . This should do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but now there is only one problem here, if I apply it in scatter3D, there are some points cannot overlap previous one, even though I set a large size of black points..how could solve it...

Comment: @4daJKong You really should not plot these overlapping points twice. You should plot separately the points with `y != 2` and separately with `y == 2`. This is what I suggested in my answer and this is also what @aminrd did in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can first have a scatter plot on records where `y != 2` and then have a scatter on `y == 2` but this time, since you want all of them `Black` instead of using `c` you set `color='black'` since these data points doesn't have different values.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from collections import Counter

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=iris.feature_names)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

points = ax.scatter(df.values[np.where(y != 2), 0],
           df.values[np.where(y != 2), 1],
           c=y[np.where(y != 2)], cmap='Dark2')

p2 = ax.scatter(df.values[np.where(y == 2), 0], df.values[np.where(y == 2), 1], color='black')

handles, _ = points.legend_elements()
labels =sorted([f'{item}: {count}' for item, count in Counter(y[np.where( y != 2)]).items()])
ax.legend([*handles, p2], [*labels, f'2: {np.sum(y == 2)}'], loc="lower right",title='clusters')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but please look at the lower right corner, I think there is some problems here

Comment: @4daJKong Error fixed

Comment: thank you again, but my actual code shows error: 'c' argument has 555 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 555, 'y' with size 555. in the line of "cmap= 'Dark2'" do you know why?

Comment: Can I only change the code part of legend? I mean overlap the color in legend?